Como hago un color-background detras de las fuentes, que sea mas estrecho?
Tengo un problema con la altura del espacio que ocupa el color-background que aparece al colocarlo en una palabra, es demasiado ancho ocupando todo el espacio.
Necesito marcar algunas palabras de los textos con un efecto como si fuese un marcador de color amarillo (los típicos marker) así que lo ideal sería estrechar esa franja.
He probado con la etiqueta <del> y con la etiqueta <mark> que hacen que se muestre el color-background, pero ocupa toda la anchura o altura de las letras, necesitaría que ocupara la mitad y centrado.
Adjunto una imagen de lo que necesito.


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Yo no pienso pinchar en un enlace raro a un sitio que podría tener un virus. SO permite adjuntar tanto código como imágenes, haz el favor y no uses servicios externos raros (además que nadie garantiza que esos sitios vayan a mantener el contenido, y la pregunta no está solo para ayudarte a ti, si no que tenemos un buscador genial para que puedan ayudar a más gente!). Por cierto, adjunta también el código para reproducir el problema (un [mre]). Cómo vamos a arreglar tu problema si no sabemos qué lo causa?? Si yo tengo que hacer tu página no será igual a cómo la hiciste tú.

En este caso yo suelo agregarle a la palabra un span de html y un background directamente al span. para que no ocupe toda la altura simplemene podes ponerle un padding en el eje Y a el mismo.

He puesto un style a la palabra a la  que se tiene que poner el background por detras es este:


<span style="background: linear-gradient(
    to top,
     white 35%,
    yellow 30%, 55%,
    white 25%);">Palabra con el background</span>
  



Y listo! con eso ya lo tenemos.
Intenté poner un class al span, más un css,  pero como el CMS con el que estoy trabajando es un wordpress, por lo que sea no me hacia caso al class y no funcionaba.
Intenté poner una class dentro del maketados Elementor, pero tampoco hacía caso.

Una recomendación: en lugar de utilizar white, usa transparent. De ese modo se verá bien incluso si el fondo no es blanco.

Puedes usar, en CSS nunca embebido en Html como he visto en alguna respuesta, el pseudoelemento ::before o ::after en tu elemento que contiene el texto para crear un contenedor vacio con un fondo del color que gustes.
Por ejemplo, si es un elemento <span></span>:


.palabra {
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
}

.palabra::before {
  /*debe tener un contenido aunque sea un estring vacío*/
  content: "";
  background-color: #00ff00;
  width: 0.8em;
  height:1em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
<span class="palabra">Ejemplo</span>



Usamos position: relative; en el texto para que al ponerle position: absolute; al pseudoelemento .texto::before este lo tome como referencia y no tome al body como la referencia, evitando que se vaya al borde superior de la pantalla.
Ya que position: absolute; hace que el elemento deje de formar parte del orden de los elementos del documento, solo respetará como contenedor a su elemento padre que tenga position: relative;
y usamos z-index: -1; para poner el rectángulo por detrás del texto. z-index permite posicionar los elementos de la página segun su eje Z (manejando su profundidad).

Debes ponerle siempre una medida de altura y hancho porque al no tener contenido no toma las medidas de ese contenido y no se podrá ver, en este caso yo use em por costumbre pero pueden ser pixeles o lo que tu quieras.
Si deseas poner un rectángulo adicional de otro color usa ::after.
Esta es la manera en que CSS te regalara elementos extra para hacer cositas creativas. Y vendrían siendo como copias del elemento principal, en este caso del span.
